# How to build vim 7.3.285 from source

Tags: vim, patch

I need to [apply a patch](https://retracile.net/wiki/VimBreakIndent) to the vim source code, but I am having trouble finding the source code for version 7.3.285. The source code from the [main vim site](http://www.vim.org/download.php) builds version 7.3.154. When I do a google search for "vim 7.3.285 source" I get mostly `.rpm` files and always something about Mandriva. I managed to find a `.scr.rpm` file and unpacked it, but then the main vim folder it had was exactly the same as the one on the vim site. My guess is that I have use the patch folder to apply the patch to version 285. So I tried the following:

- Download `.src.rpm` file [here](http://pkgs.org/mandriva-2011/mandriva-main-release-x86_64/vim-enhanced-7.3.285-1-mdv2011.0.x86_64.rpm/download/)
- unpack `.src.rpm` file like so `rpm2cpio vim-7.3.285-1.src.rpm | cpio -idmv --no-absolute-filenames`
- apply the patches to the `vim73` folder somewhat like so `for i in 'seq 0 285'; do patch -p0 < ../vim-7.3-patches/7.3.$i; done`
- then I also applied the aforementioned patch in a similar way `patch -p1 -i ../vim-7.3.285-breakindent.patch`
- finally I compiled vim: `configure`, `make` and `sudo make install`

However, and this is where it gets weird, if I issue the command `vim`, it claims to be running version `7.3.285`. If however, I issue the command `gvim` it claims to be running version `7.3.154`. It was my understanding that you compile vim and gvim gets compiled too. Does anyone have any idea what is going wrong? Is there a 7.3.285 source file I can download instead to test out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get the 7.3.285 source clone the mercurial repo and then do `hg up v7-3-285`

[full instructions here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Getting_the_Vim_source_with_Mercurial)

Comment: The same problem persists: vim runs version 7.3.285 whereas gVim runs version 7.3.154

Comment: i have no idea if they should be the same, but have you checked that you are running the correct programs with `which vim` and `which gvim` - peraps you are picking up a different version from your path?  also, i just installed gvim on my machine (from opensuse package manager) and the output from `gvim --version` and `vim --version` does appear to match.  finally - are you actually compiling gvim?  see http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Building-gvim-td3252992.html for how to check.

Comment: they are installed to `/usr/local/bin/vim` and `/usr/local/bin/gvim` and I am not sure if I am installing gvim, will follow those instructions

Comment: still trying to compile gvim, but it's interesting, `vim -g` opens gvim in version 7.3.285, but `gvim` opens it in `7.3.154`